# IP range blocked on my mac

Tags: macos, networking, mac

My Mac seems to be blocking an IP range and I would like to remove whatever is blocking it. Whenever I try to go to an IP address which starts in 5.*.*.* the request will not resolve. So if I try to visit monarch.co.uk which is hosted on 5.32.152.201 I can not view the site. The same thing with musictech.net which is hosted at 5.79.6.6 .If I visit these sites on my iPhone on the same network the sites work correctly so I know it's down to the mac. Any ideas on where I can look to unblock this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using some sort of a proxy on your Mac?

Comment: Nope no proxy that I know of

Comment: Well, if you're feeling adventurous, you could run the following command on Terminal, browse monarch.co.uk and paste the output: `sudo tcpdump host monarch.co.uk`

Comment: Did you try `traceroute 5.32.152.201` from your Mac to see how far it gets? If it's really your Mac blocking it, you shouldn't see it going even a single hop.